# Sieve Does not Work in Postfix + Dovecot + LMTP + Virtual Mailbox Setting

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot, sieve

I am setting up a spam filter on my email server but cannot get sieve to sort the mails. All spams are delivered straight to the inbox despite rules written in `.dovecot.sieve`. In mail logs Postfix reports that spams (marked with `X-Spam-Flag` in their headers) are successfully delivered to maildir, and Dovecot reports no error at all.  Dovecot version is 2.3.13 (89f716dc2).  Please advise.

/etc/postfix/**main.cf**:

```
mailbox_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
virtual_mailbox_domains = domain
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
```

/etc/dovecot/**dovecot.conf**:

```
protocols = imap lmtp
```

/etc/dovecot/conf.d/**10-master.conf**:

```
service lmtp {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
    mode = 0666
  }
}
```

/etc/dovecot/conf.d/**10-mail.conf**:

```
mail_home = /home/vmail/%d/%n/home
mail_location = maildir:/home/vmail/%d/%n
```

/etc/dovecot/conf.d/**20-lmtp.conf**:

```
protocol lmtp {
  mail_plugins = $mail_plugins sieve
}
```

/etc/dovecot/conf.d/**90-sieve.conf**:

```
sieve = ~/.dovecot.sieve
```

/home/vmail/domain.com/user1/home/**.dovecot.sieve**:

```
require ["fileinto"];

if header :contains "X-Spam-Flag" "YES" {
  fileinto "Junk";
  stop;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem myself.

First of all when using Postfix paired with Dovecot one must explicitly tell it to use Dovecot as the deliver agent for **virtual** mailboxes. Postfix should send the mail to Dovecot instead of delivering it on its own like previously shown in the logs. Restart Postfix after adding this in /etc/postfix/**main.cf**:

```
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
```

Next the "~" in /etc/dovecot/conf.d/**90-sieve.conf** means mail_location instead of mail_home. Setting `sieve = ~/.dovecot.sieve` caused Dovecot to give these outputs in the debug log:

```
Debug: sieve: include: sieve_global is not set; it is currently not possible to include `:global' scripts.
Debug: sieve: file storage: Storage path `/home/vmail/domain/user1/.dovecot.sieve' not found
Debug: sieve: storage: No default script location configured
Debug: sieve: User has no personal script
Debug: sieve: No scripts to execute: reverting to default delivery.
```

So I moved **.dovecot.sieve** to mail_location, and things started to work.